# Since having changed the carpet in my 1999 Toyota Tacoma, the a/c, dome lights, map lights and radio don’t work

Tags: electrical, toyota

I changed the fuses to see if I had a bad fuse that got shorted out when I unplugged an amp under the seat. The only thing I can figure is that I must have knocked a connection loose. Any ideas where to start troubleshooting?

Comment: All the places where the wires were when you did the carpet...

Comment: Is this an aftermarket stereo system?

Comment: There are no connections under the carpet for the dome light, the wire goes up the drivers A pillar, it must be a fuse.

Comment: Thanks! I will pull the dash this weekend to sort out a speaker issue and check for the wiring in the driver's pillar too.